# Is there a way to perform arbitrary array spreading in ByteBuddy?

Tags: byte-buddy

ByteBuddy lets you use the [`withArgumentArrayElements` method](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.19/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.html#withArgumentArrayElements-int-) to "spread" an array "into" distinct method parameters.

Is there a way to perform this spreading on *arbitrary* `Object` arrays, such as those that might be returned from a `MethodCall` invocation?

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand that question. Would you like to return multiple values in an array? If so, this is currently not possible.

Comment: e.g. `MethodCall.invoke(foo).withObjectArrayReturningMethodCallArrayElements(someOtherMethodCallHere)`